# What are exit codes for QProcess

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, exit-code, qprocess

```
QProcess *process = new QProcess(this);
QString cmd("test -c 1");
process->start(cmd);
std::cout << process->exitCode() << std::endl;
```

On executing the above code the exit code is returning 11, so this exit code is set by external process ? or it is set by default? i.e. if any process failed then this exit code is set.

Comment: The [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qprocess.html#exitCode) seems fairly clear.

Comment: Keep in mind that `start()` does not take a whole command, but is the name of a program (there is a separate argument to `start()` for arguments) so presumably exit code 11 is "command not found".

Comment: I agree. I bet you don't have an executable named exactly: `test -c 1` or `test -c 1.exe` on windows.

Comment: Also the exit code is only available after the process ended which may not be the case.

Comment: query is where the exit code is set ??.

Comment: You could do [https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#waitForStarted](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#waitForStarted) or [https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#waitForFinished](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#waitForFinished) to ensure that the process started or finished. I usually don't use either and instead use the signals and slots that QProcess provides to tell me that the process started or finished.